# What attack does the "encrypt ENV variables in transit" aws lambda feature prevent?

Tags: security, aws-lambda, containers

The [aws lambda docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html) recommend you encrypt your env variables if they contain sensitive information, and then decrypt them within you lambda function.

[image: aws sensitive env variables documentation screenshot]

See screenshots of the feature attached. AWS provides sample code that you would use to decrypt the ENV variables from within your function.

[image: aws lambda console env variables screenshot]
[image: aws lambda sample code for decrypting encrypted-env variables]

I'm trying to understand more about how AWS Lambda functions work, and in this case I'm trying to understand what attack this feature prevents against. My understanding is that by default ENV variables are encrypted at rest by aws. This means that presumably they are sitting somewhere (s3...) in encrypted form until the function get's triggered.

When the function gets triggered/deployed, what happens exactly and why does this make my ENV variables vulnerable without the extra encryption step?

Comment: So, you already know variables are available in plain text when functions are triggered. Now imagine I find some vulnerability in your code that allows me to get access to that environment. I will then have access to every piece of unencrypted information you were keeping there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying your lambda via IaC like Terraform, your Terraform repo could potentially have sensitive environment variables in clear text in the code e.g. in the tfvars file. Using this encryption feature, you could specify cipher text in the code instead. Note: there are probably other ways to deal with sensitive data e.g. gitcrypt, Terraform Cloud, etc., but this would be one way to get embedded secrets out of the code.

Another reason is if the AWS account isn't locked down, someone with access could go sniffing around in the AWS console and discover the unencrypted environment variables e.g. API keys/tokens, etc. and copy them down for malicious purposes...